# Regular Expression - Not matching certain characters and position of characters

Tags: regex

SOLUTION:
Finally solved it using the regex provided by Gary_W below and a simple PowerShell command that uses the discussed replacement function. So there was no need to use the built in regex activity in the software we use. Here´s the PS:
"100,000.00" -replace "([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.]",""

Regular Expressions are freaking me out. I cannot get used to that logic. However, I think my current RE problem is a quite simple one bur I cannot make it work :(

So here´s what I want to achieve:
I want the RE to match only the digits before the last two decimal places. 
Thus, the RE must ignore any "." and "," AND always the last two digits.

```
> Examples:
> 1.000.000,00 --> 1000000
> 123,456.00 --> 123456
> 100.000,00 --> 100000
> 10.000,00 --> 10000
> 10,000.00 --> 10000
> 1.000,00 --> 1000 
> 100,00 --> 100
> 99.88 --> 99 
> 99,88 --> 99 
> 1,23 --> 1 
> ...
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Where's the regex pattern you're attempting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I do not have a pattern to work with... Nothing worked so far...

Comment: Looks like this `/(?:[\.,]\d\d)\b/g` creates the desired list on http://regexr.com/.

Comment: @Deathgrip Thanks but it´s not the desired match. What I need is that the regex matches 10 000 if 10.000,00 or 10,000.00 is provided. The regex must match only the digits except the last two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in Oracle, for what it's worth.  Maybe the regex used here will give you an idea.  Read the regex as "Look for a match of a comma or a decimal followed by 2 digits at the end of the line, OR a comma or a decimal and replace with nothing.
Note the match for the optional decimal places at the end needs to be first in the regex, otherwise the single characters are matched first, making the 2 decimal places non-existent and thus not matched.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select '1.000.000,00' from dual union all
     select '123,456.00' from dual union all
     select '100.000,00' from dual union all
     select '10.000,00' from dual union all
     select '10,000.00' from dual union all
     select '1.000,00' from dual union all
     select '100,00' from dual union all
     select '99.88' from dual union all
     select '99,88' from dual union all
     select '1,23' from dual union all
     select '3' from dual
   )
   select str,
          regexp_replace(str, '([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.]') fixed
   from tbl;

STR          FIXED
------------ ------------
1.000.000,00 1000000
123,456.00   123456
100.000,00   100000
10.000,00    10000
10,000.00    10000
1.000,00     1000
100,00       100
99.88        99
99,88        99
1,23         1
3            3

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Just saw the regexr link, plugging in my regex looks like it works with the global flag. The characters you wish to remove are highlighted.

Comment: Thanks Gary_W. If I enter your expression /([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.]/g in regexr it highlights only the , and . just like this expression  [,.]. Your oracle example is exactly what I need.

Comment: Yeah, then you delete what is highlighted.  You don't say what OS/RDBMS/editor/language you are doing this in so its hard to advise further.  regexr adds the /g for global but there is usually a /d option for delete depending on the implementation.  Not all regex implementations are created equal.

Comment: I just saw Mauro's comment about using replace in the tools menu on regexr.  With my regex, clear the replace to show the delete of the match. Your environment will dictate the best option for you.  Let us know which one works.

Comment: Ok I´m going to check what this software actually uses as regex engine and test it right away. Stay tuned and many thanks!

Comment: So, the tool where the regex should be used can just handle basic regex. They implemented a so called regex activity. Just tested it with your regex ([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.] and it returns for 10,000.00 this: ,.00    So what I would need in order to make it finally work is a inverted version of ([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.] so that 10000 is returned.

Comment: Another option would be to use the available PowerShell activity. I must confess that I do not know how to handle this in PS - especially with this replace option...

Comment: Finally solved it using your provided regex and a simple powershell command that uses the discussed replacement function. So there was no need to use the built in regex activity. Here´s the PS:

"100,000.00" -replace "([,.]\d{2}$)|[,.]",""

Answer (score 1):

In which language/with which tool? With `sed`, you can do:

`sed 's/\(.*\)[\.,]../\1/;s/[\.,]//g'`

In `perl` it's similar, just without the initial backslashes:

`perl -pe 's/(.*)[\.,]../\1/;s/[\.,]//g'`

This is done with two regexes, by the way. The first one reads "save all that you can, up to a dot or a comma followed by two chars, and then replace the whole match with that". The second one reads "replace all dots and commas with nothing", that is, "remove all dots and commas".

In [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) you can use "Replace" in **Tools** to replace the match with the first capture group. Just put `(.*)[\.,]..` in Expression, and `$1` in Replace, to see the first regex working. Then you can do something similar with the second one, as regexr doesn't support chaining of expressions, as far as I can see.

Comment: Great, thanks Mauro. It´s not for a specific language. If it would work here [link](http://regexr.com) it´s enough. However, your sed and perl examples do not work on regexr. Do I miss something here?

Comment: The tool where it is used can only handle a single regex - just like regexr works.